# Resolving race conditions on recursive autoresertevent

Tags: c#, multithreading, autoresetevent

In the code below I have a class that is used for controlling synchronization called KernalRecursiveAutoResetEvent. This has a Lock and Leave method which calls the AutoResetEvent WaitOne() for locking and Set() for releasing. I have setup a loop so I can call a method that deals with a shared resource. In the method Increment i add an int to a shared list. The race coniditon is faling because Leave is being called faster than Lock. Is there a better way of controlling the execution? TheInvalidOperation exception is thrown because the condition checking if the current thread is equal to the owning thread is executed just before the owning thread is set via the Lock() method.

Any tips?

```
        class KernalRecursiveAutoResetEvent : IDisposable
            {
                private AutoResetEvent m_lock = new AutoResetEvent(false);
                private int m_owningThreadId = 0;
                private int m_recusionCount = 0;

                public void Lock()
                {
                    int currentThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

                    if (m_owningThreadId == currentThreadId)
                    {
                        m_recusionCount++;
                        return;
                    }

                    m_lock.WaitOne();

                    m_owningThreadId = currentThreadId;
                    m_recusionCount = 1;
                }

                public void Leave()
                {
                    if (m_owningThreadId != Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
                        throw new InvalidOperationException();

                    if (--m_recusionCount == 0)
                    {
                        m_owningThreadId = 0;
                        m_lock.Set();
                    }
                }

                public void Dispose()
                {
                    m_lock.Close();
                }
            }

    using (var rare = new KernalRecursiveAutoResetEvent())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
                    {
                        var t = new Thread(a => Increment(ref i, rare));
                        t.Start();
                        rare.Lock();
                    }
                }

private static void Increment(ref int i, object _lock)
        {
            Increment(ref i);

            if (_lock is KernalRecursiveAutoResetEvent)
            {
                var m_lock = _lock as KernalRecursiveAutoResetEvent;
                m_lock.Leave();
            }
            else if (_lock is KernalModeMutexSimpleWaitLock)
            {
                var m_lock = _lock as KernalModeMutexSimpleWaitLock;
                m_lock.Leave();
            }
            else if (_lock is KernalModeSemaphoreSimpleWaitLock)
            {
                var m_lock = _lock as KernalModeSemaphoreSimpleWaitLock;
                m_lock.Leave();
            }
            else if (_lock is KernalModeSimpleWaitLock)
            {
                var m_lock = _lock as KernalModeSimpleWaitLock;
                m_lock.Leave();
            }
        }

private static void Increment(ref int i)
        {
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: "Leave is being called faster than Lock" - so why don't you post the code which calls `Leave`? You could replace your synchronisation primitive with something more conventional (i.e. `Monitor`, which has the exact functionality described), but if your code is calling `Exit` before `Enter`, your problem will still remain.

Comment: The code that calls leave is simple, it increments I and calls rare.Leave() (which underlyingly calls AutoResetEvent.Set().

The issue is not understanding Monitor.Enter or Exit/TryExit it is understanding the race condition and controlling that. There are some fundamental issues with the FCL static Monitor.Enter and Leave/TryLeave etc. This isnt an issue with understanding why its not locking, it is not locking because of the failure in controlling the race conditions. I want to know how/why Leave is being called before Lock

Answer (score 1):

This is unnecessarily complicated. You should just use `lock()` around the code where you add the new int to the list. Of course, the object you lock on, should be common between all 'threads'.

example:

```
var lockObj = new object();

for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    // what do you mean `red i`, by the way? It's a value type.
    var t = new Thread(a => Increment(ref i, lockObj));
    t.Start();
}
```

Inside `Increment`:

```
lock (lockObj)
{
  someIntList.Add(i); // or whatever. Only one thread at a time can do this!
}
```

Of course, your `lockObj` could also be static.

Also, don't start new threads. Use `Task` instead.

Comment: The reason I dont want to call Monitor.Enter (lock) is because there are no issues in my understanding of how to lock on shared resources plus there are some fundamental issues with the FCL static Monitor.Enter and I want to use Kernal Mode Sync for a better understanding.

The real underlying issue I am trying to solve is why the Leave method is being called faster than the Enter? How is the main thread slower in reaching the Lock than the execution of a separate thread that calls leave>